# DNS Record or Port Mapping

Tags: domain-name-system, port-forwarding, internal-dns

All,

I have a web server sitting inside of a production network. This web server, tdxs3, has been assigned an external IP address of 96.2.192.139 which DNS should point to it's internal IP address of 172.30.115.246. When trying to hit it from the outside using tdxs3.dsdk12.net, nothing pops up. Hit the IP however, and it works. (Internally, everything works, of course - nothing to resolve) By the way, the switch routes the external IP to the internal IP. So, I think it's port mapped properly. So I'm fairly certain this is a DNS issue. I've changed the DNS record, incremented the SOA serial and restarted named. (FreeBSD box) But even after 24 hours, I'm getting nothing. (I have two DNS zone masters, one for external, the other for internal)

This is the record for external:

tdxs3 IN A 96.2.192.139

tdxs3 IN CNAME tdxs3.dsdk12.net

And internal:

tdxs3 A 172.30.115.246

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: If you query the DNS server(s) with `nslookup`/`dig` do you get the expected answer? What is your zone TTL?

Comment: Nslookup and dig both return the expected results. (From the inside) From the outside, dig returned the expected result, nslookup failed. I've dropped the TTL down to 60, until I nail this down.

Answer (score 1):

- CNAME records should not co-exist with any other record type.
- CNAME records should not point back to themselves.

As such your nameservers may even be failing the zone. Check your logs.